# How to set up a Template_loader for Freemarker 2.3.30

Tags: java, templates, freemarker

I was using [this](https://www.viralpatel.net/freemaker-template-hello-world-tutorial/) tutorial to learn FreeMarker but it seems deprecated. I added

```
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_30);
```

for the Configuration object, but then I get the following exception:

`freemarker.template.TemplateNotFoundException: Don't know where to load template "C:\\test\\helloworld.ftl" from because the "template_loader" FreeMarker setting wasn't set (Configuration.setTemplateLoader), so it's null`

How to set up the TemplateLoader correctly in this tutorial example?

Comment: I could solve it myself, the direction for the template needs to be loaded separately with cfg.setDirectoryForTemplateLoading(new File("C:/test")); and then load the template without the dir Template template = cfg.getTemplate("helloworld.ftl");

Answer (score 3):

the same thing happened to me but I found this on the internet, we have to load the folder that we use within "resources"

```
final Configuration freeMarCfg = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_30);

        final ClassTemplateLoader loader = new ClassTemplateLoader(Main3.class, "/templates");
        freeMarCfg.setTemplateLoader(loader);
        freeMarCfg.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        freeMarCfg.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);

        final String fileTemplate = "getPositions.ftl";

        final Template weatherByCityTmplate = freeMarCfg.getTemplate(fileTemplate);
```

i saw it on this site: https://www.concretepage.com/freemarker/freemarker-configuration-with-classtemplateloader-example